# How do I get this bootstrap Row & Col scaffolding right in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks for taking a look at my question.

I'm trying to get PHP to only print out rows every 3 cols, sort of like a grid. I added this logic where if the i is ever 0, It will print out the row, but I don't get the correct bootstrap Scaffolding.

If there are only 3 cols there's no Row surrounding it and if there's more than 3 some cols are in the row while others are not.

**Here's the code (BTW this is a WordPress loop):**

```
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <section class="our_attorney our_attorney_style_two container">
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
      $loop->the_post();
        $lp = (( ++$i % 3 == 0 ) ? true : false );
        if($lp){echo '<div class="row">';}
      ?>

     <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="attorney_member">
        <div class="img_holder">
          <img src="<?php the_field('field_1'); ?>" alt="images" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="opacity transition3s">
            <div class="info">
              <a href="#">
                <h4><?php the_field('field_2'); ?></h4>
                <span><?php the_field("field_3"); ?></span>
              </a>
            </div> <!-- End .info -->
          </div> <!-- End /opacity -->
        </div> <!-- /img_holder -->
      </div> <!-- /attorney_member -->
    </div>

  <?php
    if($lp){echo '</div>'; }
  ?>

<?php
      } // end while
   } // end if
 ?>
 </section>
```

**Here's the HTML output if they're are 4 cols:**

```
<section>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
</section>
```

As you can see all of the cols except the 3rd are out of the row, I really need some help on understanding how to achieve the scaffolding, I've searched solutions here on Stack overflow but none work.. Maybe it's because it's WordPress code?

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I've created a simple example for you to understand.

```
<?php
$days = array( 'sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' );

echo '<div class="row">';
$i = 1;
foreach ($days as $day) {

    echo $day .', ';

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }

    $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Output will be

```
<div class="row">sunday, monday, tuesday, </div>
<div class="row">wednesday, thursday, friday, </div>
<div class="row">saturday, </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you want to have in one row 3 columns with your desired grid width:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  if($i % 3 == 0) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
  }
  ?>

  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>

  <?php
  if((($i+1) % 3) == 0) {
  echo '</div>';
  }
  $i++;
endwhile;
?>

</section>
```

Bootstrap grid is very simple - columns are in rows, rows are in container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```